# How do I change the screen font size when using a virtual console?

Tags: linux, console, fonts, resolution

Using LDXE and Ubuntu, I can log into a virtual console via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

The text is far too small. How do I change the screen resolution to get a larger font?

Comment: This might help : http://askubuntu.com/a/173221/434885

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should edit the file `/etc/default/console-setup` and change the `FONTSIZE` variable. Once you've made your changes you must reconfigure your terminal by running:

```
$ sudo service console-setup restart
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but the problem is knowing what possible settings are allowed.  The default font is "Fixed" and its largest size is 8x16.  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` allows you to see what the options are. (answer from @boulder_ruby)

Answer (score 10):

@Spack's answer didn't work for my raspberry-pi, but I found a set of instructions that did work for me [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-change-the-command-line-font-size/)

To sum it up

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
#select "UTF-8"
#select "Guess optimal character set"
#select "Terminus"
#select 16*32 (my selection for a 7 inch monitor on raspberry pi)
```

Comment: This only sort of worked for me...  :(  I seem to have to type `setupcon` in the virtual terminal to get it to be used (on each reboot and on each terminal!).

Answer (score -4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> - use the plus symbol on the text keypad not on the numeric pad.

Comment: I tried this (on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS). It just sends a `+` character.

Comment: When he says "Ctrl+Alt+F1" makes clear he doesn't mean a _terminal emulator_, more info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4131/209677).